# My randomizing code doesn't work off-line

Tags: php

I'm a php noob and I just made a little script from some other scripts I found on the net. It picks 3 random images from a folder named "Random" and shows them.

While I run the script online it works, but when I try to run it offline on xampp I get this error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: random2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\finaleasd2.php on line 69**

It's the line where the images are given their name as a variable.
I think it's due to the script that doesn't get the folder name right when offline, but I'm not sure: what's going wrong? :)

BTW this is the script and line 69 is **while (!$random2 || $random2 == $random1)** { (I know, it's a mess! :D)

Thank you for your help and time! :)

```
<?php function RandomFile($folder='', $extensions='.*'){
   // fix path:
    $folder = trim($folder);
    $folder = ($folder == '') ? './' : $folder;

    // check folder:
    if (!is_dir($folder)){ die('invalid folder given!'); }

    // create files array
    $files = array();

    // open directory
    if ($dir = @opendir($folder)){

        // go trough all files:
        while($file = readdir($dir)){

            if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                preg_match('/\.('.$extensions.')$/', $file)){

                // feed the array:
                $files[] = $file;                
            }            
        }        
        // close directory
        closedir($dir);    
    }
    else {
        die('Could not open the folder "'.$folder.'"');
    }

    if (count($files) == 0){
        die('No files where found :-(');
    }

    // seed random function:
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    // get an random index:
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($files)-1);

    // check again:
    if (!isset($files[$rand])){
        die('Array index was not found! very strange!');
    }

    // return the random file:
    return $folder . "/" . $files[$rand];

}

//assegna i nomi delle variabili ai file
$random1 = RandomFile("random");
while (!$random2 || $random2 == $random1) {
    $random2 = RandomFile("random");
}
while (!$random3 || $random3 == $random1 || $random3 == $random2) {
    $random3 = RandomFile("random");
}


//la parte dedicata alla creazione dei testi alternativi partendo da un file di testo

$quotesfile = "quotes.txt"; //Relative path to and the filename of the file that contains your quotes. 



$array = @file("$quotesfile");  
// Crea un array con le citazioni
$quote = rand(0, count($array)-1);


$titolo = array_rand($array, 3);



// la parte sotto crea un div con dentro due immagini statiche, i lati della panchina, e quattro caricate a caso. le immagini hanno
// come titoli le variabili estratte casualmente dall' array di nome array preso dal file di testo di prima
?>
```

Comment: Does the script still show the images despite the notice?

Comment: Nope, the images appear as broken or missing

Comment: So, may I ask what's your question about `Undefined variable`?

Answer (score 1):

If your only problem is the `undefined variable`, it's easy.

The server settings are different on your local and remote servers so one returns the error and the other doesn't, but when you ask `!$random2` before it exists it will return an error.

So simply set `$random2` to `false` before the `while` loop.

The same goes for `$random3`.