# Script for random images doesn't work OFFLINE

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My randomizing code doesn't work off-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664574/my-randomizing-code-doesnt-work-off-line)

This scripts picks 3 random images from a folder named Random and displays them, but it doesn't work offline.

With xampp gives this error while showing images as broken links **Notice: Undefined variable: random2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sito\finaleasd2.php on line 69**

Line 69 here is `while (!$random2 || $random2 == $random1) {`

What's happening?

```
<?php function RandomFile($folder='', $extensions='.*'){
   // fix path:
    $folder = trim($folder);
    $folder = ($folder == '') ? './' : $folder;

    // check folder:
    if (!is_dir($folder)){ die('invalid folder given!'); }

    // create files array
    $files = array();

    // open directory
    if ($dir = @opendir($folder)){

        // go trough all files:
        while($file = readdir($dir)){

            if (!preg_match('/^\.+$/', $file) and 
                preg_match('/\.('.$extensions.')$/', $file)){

                // feed the array:
                $files[] = $file;                
            }            
        }        
        // close directory
        closedir($dir);    
    }
    else {
        die('Could not open the folder "'.$folder.'"');
    }

    if (count($files) == 0){
        die('No files where found :-(');
    }

    // seed random function:
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

    // get an random index:
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($files)-1);

    // check again:
    if (!isset($files[$rand])){
        die('Array index was not found! very strange!');
    }

    // return the random file:
    return $folder . "/" . $files[$rand];

}

//assegna i nomi delle variabili ai file
$random1 = RandomFile("random");
while (!$random2 || $random2 == $random1) {
    $random2 = RandomFile("random");
}
while (!$random3 || $random3 == $random1 || $random3 == $random2) {
    $random3 = RandomFile("random");
}


//la parte dedicata alla creazione dei testi alternativi partendo da un file di testo

$quotesfile = "quotes.txt"; //Relative path to and the filename of the file that contains your quotes. 



$array = @file("$quotesfile");  
// Crea un array con le citazioni
$quote = rand(0, count($array)-1);


$titolo = array_rand($array, 3);



// la parte sotto crea un div con dentro due immagini statiche, i lati della panchina, e quattro caricate a caso. le immagini hanno
// come titoli le variabili estratte casualmente dall' array di nome array preso dal file di testo di prima
?>
```

Comment: Copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664574/my-randomizing-code-doesnt-work-off-line

Comment: A notice is not an error ... hence this is not necessarily the reason for your problem.

Comment: What does "OFFLINE" have to do with anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "offline", but you get a notice. This means you are reading a variable that was never set. This didn't generate a notice (mind you, this is not an error, this is a notice) in earlier versions I guess, and it doesn't mean your code doesn't work.

You can fix it by decalring all variables (it is probably `$random2`, so start your script with something like `$random2 = false;` or `$random2 = array();`)

You could also, but this isn't as  nice, set the error-reporting to not-include notices.

Comment: Or he just had his other server configured differently w.r.t. error reporting.

Comment: The notice actually disappeared, but the images still don't show up, appearing as broken links/images

P.S.
It works on the other server

Comment: True ofcourse! That was more of a brainfart then an actual addition to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general tip, picking three random entries can be made much, *much* simpler:

```
// build array of files once

// assume here $files is something like array('foo.jpeg', 'bar.jpeg', …)

shuffle($files);
$threeRandomImages = array_slice($files, 0, 3);
```

Done.

Comment: Well, sure, it's simpler when you abstract out the _entire_ "get list of filenames" code. What a silly answer.

Comment: @Tomalak The *get-list-of-filenames* code doesn't need to change, only the back-asswards logic of picking three random files. Incidentally it'll probably also fix the OP's particular problem with missing variables.

Comment: Well it still doesn't work: images appear as missing. I think there's something wrong in the way the script reads the path to the images, but I'm not sure. I don't understand why it works online and doesn't offline!

Comment: @tommaso What are you actually doing with the picked files? I can't see you outputting them anywhere.

Comment: @deceze
Just displaying them in a row and assigning them random "title" tags from a txt file.





<div id="random_imgs">
     
<img class="sopra" src="bordosinistro.jpg"/><img class="sopra" src="/<?php echo $random1; ?>" title="<?php echo $array[$titolo[0]]?>" /><img class="sopra" src="/<?php echo $random2; ?>" title="<?php echo $array[$titolo[1]]?>" /><img class="sopra" src="/<?php echo $random3; ?>" title="<?php echo $array[$titolo[2]]?>" /><img src="dx7.jpg" class="sfondo"/>
     
</div>

Comment: @tomasso So what's the actual output of that? Can you see the images when accessing that `src` URL directly? If not, why?

Comment: I think you found the problem! If I look at the url, it goes http://localhost/random/DSC_6043.jpg while it should be http://localhost/sito/random/DSC_6043.jpg... well! Do I feel DUMB! :D I just misplaced the files and put them in a folder when the should have gone to the root of the apache server on my pc! THANK YOU!